# Why is my UIButton ignoring its autolayout constraint to stretch its height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a button whose image is set dynamically at run time.  As a result, to maintain the appropriate ratio, I have the following code in where the image is set:

```
[super removeConstraint:self.ratioConstraint];
float ratio=photo.size.height/photo.size.width;
self.ratioConstraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:self.button
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 multiplier:ratio
                                                   constant:0];
[self.ratioConstraint setPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh];
[super addConstraint:self.ratioConstraint];
```

I even applied a `[self layoutSubviews]` to let me check the frame.  When I queried the frame, it was right.  The ratio of 1 was honored and the height was set equal to the width.

But in ViewWillAppear, the same query produces the same impossible results:  the height of the frame is stretching to let the image grow to it's full height.  Despite having the above constraint, which should limit the height based on the existing (and honored) width limits.

Even more infuriating, until I set the image to something new at runtime (i. e. by taking the camera), the restraint appears to be functional -- the placeholder image is squashed down horizontally, and compacts itself vertically to fit.  It's only once I take a photo that that height explodes, ignoring it's constraint for no apparent reason.

In case it matters, the above code is executed in a custom subclass of UIControl, which is then embedded in a UIView ('ContentView') which is itself embedded in a scroll view.  The width restrictions are, more or less:

"ContentView" has a width equal to the ViewController's view.
The UIControl view then has it's width set to a value that either gives it about half or about one quarter of the screen's width, depending on the exact control.  (I have five of them; one gets half the screen width, the others all get one quarter and are arranged in a row).
The UIControl then sets the UIButton's width equal to it's own via the constraint: H:|-(0)-[Button]-(0)-| .

Even more annoyingly, I ran through and inspected *every* constraint from the UIViewController's view down -- a bit of recursive logic that pulled up every constraint in a given view and it's subviews that applied to a given subject.  I then ran that against each object in the view hierarchy, and got... zip.  No constraints that were interfering.  Nothing that should have effected the height of hte buttons in question *except* the code above, which apply the ratio constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The solution actually proved to be rather embarrassingly obvious, though I'm not sure I understand *why* the solution worked (or the code above didn't).

In the code above, I used the constant 'UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh'; in my init code, I used the constant 'UILayoutPriorityRequired'.

Apparently, the photo's desire to stretch out to it's full size is a high priority, so I could only override that 'silent' constraint by upping my own to required.  (Interestingly, the bug actually existed before I added the priority calls at all, suggesting that a constraint doesn't start out with that priority -- something I suspect may confuse more than one programmer out there when they trip over it).